# How to connect to SQL Server in qlikview12

Tags: sql-server, qlikview

I encounter a problem connecting to my SQL Server database. We have 2 servers, the first is an application server & the second is a database server (which hosts SQL Server).

I can not connect to SQL Server directly and should first login to application server then remote to DB server (also we can not ping the database server directly and in application server you can ping database server).

How can I connect to the database server in qlik?

Comment: This is a network issue (firewall, lan, subnet mask etc.)

Answer (score -1):

First you need to install SQL server on your machine and Connect it. Now Click on Edit script in Qlikview and in the data tab below you will see Database options like OLEDB and ODBC. For sql server select OLEDB connection and then select **Microsoft OLE Db Provider for sql server**, click next and select server name which has used for connecting to sql server, then select Windows NT security and database which is created on that server.

Is this helpful?